# Xbox 360, trouble with display

Tags: xbox-360

I have an Xbox 360 and for some reason whenever I turn it on the display is black. The controller turns on I hear the fan everything is on except for the display. I've tried unplugging the Xbox and plugging it back in I tried changing the AV cord to AV1 and AV2 and it did the same thing. I would just like to what the promblem is and if I can change it. Oh and another thing I just remembered is the power blocks light is green while the Xbox is "on" and so are the sounds

Comment: What about via HDMI? Can you test that?

Comment: Have you tried a different video cord, or just different ports? Could be the cord.

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same problem. I fixed it by unplugging the tv and replugging it back in.   (Power cord)

-Not sure if it's the same as your situation